# How to evualate a function in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, python-requests, sleep

I am trying to stream data in real time while comparing two values. However, it seems as if the function is only being evaluated once. However, `time.sleep` is also being ran, because it pauses in between loops. However the time is always the same.

```
x = f'https://api.polygon.io/v1/last/stocks/SPY?{key}'
def get_data():
    time.sleep(5)
    data = requests.get(x)
    json_data = data.json()
    
    #last price, datetime object
    print ((json_data['last'])['price'], epoch_to_date_time( (json_data['last'])['timestamp'] ).__str__())
    return (json_data['last'])['price']


def while_no_match(x):
    counter = 0
    while get_data()!=x and counter < 5 :
        get_data()
        counter +=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while_no_match(100)
```

```
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
316.63 2020-07-08 19:01:42.457000
```

Comment: How do you not get a name error?

Comment: x is a link to the API i am using. Also, thanks for the tips.

Comment: You are right. It is probably the API. I wasn't having this issue during market-hours. Removing the down vote would be nice. It's hard enough asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after running get_data manually a few time i received the following outputs:

```
316.69 2020-07-08 19:36:39.535000
316.71 2020-07-08 19:37:07.138000
316.71 2020-07-08 19:37:07.138000
```

It must be the API.